# sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial never completes

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial` (I've tried installing desktop-full which gets to the urdf-tutorial and hits the same problem) and the get never seems to complete. Its like its downloading the same package again and again...
After a few hours, the console looks like this and I've downloaded 7.5 GBytes :

```
Get:14837 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14838 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14839 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14840 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14841 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14842 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14843 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14844 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14845 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14846 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14847 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14848 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14849 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14850 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14851 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14852 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14853 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14854 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14855 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14856 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14857 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14858 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14859 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14860 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14861 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14862 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
Get:14863 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial i386 0.2.4-0trusty-20160801-172840-0700 [490 kB]
```

Am I doing something stupid?

Thanks,
Tom

---

edit: I have managed to get `ros-indigo-base` installed and am currently investigating what what sits between my VM and our ISP. There is no proxy that I know of... Thanks for the help...

```
osboxes@osboxes:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  curl debhelper dh-apparmor fontconfig-config gir1.2-gtk-2.0 graphviz
  libassimp-dev libassimp3 libatk1.0-dev libavcodec-dev libavcodec54
  libavformat-dev libavformat54 libavutil-dev libavutil52
  libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev libcdt5 libcgraph6 libcurl3
  libcurl4-openssl-dev libcv-dev libcvaux-dev libdc1394-22 libdc1394-22-dev
  libdrm-dev libeigen3-dev libfontconfig1 libfontconfig1-dev libfreeimage-dev
  libfreeimage3 libfreetype6-dev libgcrypt11 libgcrypt11-dev
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglib2.0-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
  libgnutls-dev libgnutlsxx27 libgpg-error-dev libgsm1 libgtk2.0-dev
  libgtkglext1 libgvc6 libgvpr2 libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0
  libharfbuzz-icu0 libharfbuzz0b libhighgui-dev libice-dev libidn11
  libidn11-dev libilmbase-dev libilmbase6 libjasper-dev libjbig-dev
  libjpeg-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev libkrb5-dev liblzma-dev
  libmail-sendmail-perl libmp3lame0 libogre-1.8-dev libogre-1.8.0
  libopencv-calib3d-dev libopencv-calib3d2.4 libopencv-contrib-dev
  libopencv-contrib2.4 libopencv-core-dev libopencv-core2.4 libopencv-dev
  libopencv-features2d-dev libopencv-features2d2.4 libopencv-flann-dev
  libopencv-flann2.4 libopencv-gpu-dev libopencv-gpu2.4 libopencv-highgui-dev
  libopencv-highgui2.4 libopencv-imgproc-dev libopencv-imgproc2.4
  libopencv-legacy-dev libopencv-legacy2.4 libopencv-ml-dev libopencv-ml2.4
  libopencv-objdetect-dev libopencv-objdetect2.4 libopencv-ocl-dev
  libopencv-ocl2.4 libopencv-photo-dev libopencv-photo2.4
  libopencv-stitching-dev libopencv-stitching2.4 libopencv-superres-dev
  libopencv-superres2.4 libopencv-ts-dev libopencv-ts2.4 libopencv-video-dev
  libopencv-video2.4 libopencv-videostab-dev libopencv-videostab2.4
  libopencv2.4-java libopencv2.4-jni libopenexr-dev libopenexr6 libopenjpeg2
  libopus0 libp11-kit-dev libpango1.0-dev libpathplan4 libphonon4
  libpixman-1-dev libpng12-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libpyside-dev
  libpyside-py3-1.2 libpyside1.2 libqt4-dev libqt4-dev-bin libqt4-opengl-dev
  libqt4-qt3support libqtwebkit-dev libraw1394-dev libraw1394-tools
  librtmp-dev libschroedinger-1.0-0 libshiboken-dev libshiboken-py3-1.2
  libshiboken1.2 libsm-dev libswscale-dev libswscale2
  libsys-hostname-long-perl libtasn1-6-dev libtbb2 libtiff5-dev libtiffxx5
  liburdfdom-dev liburdfdom-headers-dev liburdfdom-model-state0.2
  liburdfdom-model0.2 liburdfdom-sensor0.2 liburdfdom-world0.2 libva1
  libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk-media2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0 libx11-dev libx11-doc
  libx11-xcb-dev libx264-142 libxau-dev libxaw7-dev libxcb-dri2-0-dev
  libxcb-dri3-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-present-dev libxcb-randr0-dev
  libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-sync-dev
  libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxcb1-dev libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev
  libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxft-dev libxi-dev
  libxinerama-dev libxml2-utils libxmu-dev libxmu-headers libxpm-dev
  libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev libxshmfence-dev libxt-dev libxvidcore4
  libxxf86vm-dev libyaml-cpp-dev libyaml-cpp0.5 libzzip-0-13 libzzip-dev
  mesa-common-dev opencv-data phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer
  phonon-backend-gstreamer-common phonon-backend-gstreamer1.0 po-debconf
  python-opencv python-pycurl python-pyside python-pyside.phonon
  python-pyside.qtcore python-pyside.qtdeclarative python-pyside.qtgui
  python-pyside.qthelp python-pyside.qtnetwork python-pyside.qtopengl
  python-pyside.qtscript python-pyside.qtsql python-pyside.qtsvg
  python-pyside.qttest python-pyside.qtuitools python-pyside.qtwebkit
  python-pyside.qtxml python-qt4-dev python-sip-dev python-urlgrabber
  python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxversion qt4-linguist-tools qt4-qmake
  ros-indigo-angles ros-indigo-image-geometry ros-indigo-image-transport
  ros-indigo-interactive-markers ros-indigo-joint-state-publisher
  ros-indigo-kdl-conversions ros-indigo-kdl-parser ros-indigo-laser-geometry
  ros-indigo-map-msgs ros-indigo-media-export ros-indigo-orocos-kdl
  ros-indigo-pr2-description ros-indigo-python-orocos-kdl
  ros-indigo-python-qt-binding ros-indigo-resource-retriever
  ros-indigo-robot-state-publisher ros-indigo-rviz ros-indigo-tf
  ros-indigo-tf-conversions ros-indigo-tf2 ros-indigo-tf2-kdl
  ros-indigo-tf2-msgs ros-indigo-tf2-py ros-indigo-tf2-ros ros-indigo-urdf
  ros-indigo-urdf-parser-plugin ros-indigo-xacro shiboken sip-dev
  x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-core-dev x11proto-damage-dev
  x11proto-dri2-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-gl-dev x11proto-input-dev
  x11proto-kb-dev x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-render-dev x11proto-xext-dev
  x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev x11proto-xinerama-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Suggested packages:
  dh-make apparmor-easyprof graphviz-doc libgsm1-dev libogg-dev
  libschroedinger-dev libspeex-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libcairo2-doc
  libcurl4-doc libcurl3-dbg libeigen3-doc libmrpt-dev rng-tools
  libgcrypt11-doc libglib2.0-doc gnutls26-doc gnutls-bin libgtk2.0-doc
  libice-doc krb5-doc liblzma-doc ogre-1.8-doc opus-tools libpango1.0-doc
  imagemagick firebird-dev libsqlite0-dev qt4-dev-tools qt4-doc unixodbc-dev
  libraw1394-doc libsm-doc libxaw-doc libxcb-doc libxext-doc libxt-doc
  phonon-backend-vlc gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly phonon4qt5-backend-gstreamer
  libmail-box-perl libcurl4-gnutls-dev python-pycurl-dbg python-sip-doc
  wx2.8-doc wx2.8-examples editra
The following NEW packages will be installed
  debhelper dh-apparmor gir1.2-gtk-2.0 graphviz libassimp-dev libassimp3
  libatk1.0-dev libavcodec-dev libavcodec54 libavformat-dev libavformat54
  libavutil-dev libavutil52 libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev libcdt5
  libcgraph6 libcurl4-openssl-dev libcv-dev libcvaux-dev libdc1394-22
  libdc1394-22-dev libdrm-dev libeigen3-dev libfontconfig1-dev
  libfreeimage-dev libfreeimage3 libfreetype6-dev libgcrypt11-dev
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglib2.0-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
  libgnutls-dev libgnutlsxx27 libgpg-error-dev libgsm1 libgtk2.0-dev
  libgtkglext1 libgvc6 libgvpr2 libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0
  libhighgui-dev libice-dev libidn11-dev libilmbase-dev libilmbase6
  libjasper-dev libjbig-dev libjpeg-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev
  libkrb5-dev liblzma-dev libmail-sendmail-perl libmp3lame0 libogre-1.8-dev
  libogre-1.8.0 libopencv-calib3d-dev libopencv-calib3d2.4
  libopencv-contrib-dev libopencv-contrib2.4 libopencv-core-dev
  libopencv-core2.4 libopencv-dev libopencv-features2d-dev
  libopencv-features2d2.4 libopencv-flann-dev libopencv-flann2.4
  libopencv-gpu-dev libopencv-gpu2.4 libopencv-highgui-dev
  libopencv-highgui2.4 libopencv-imgproc-dev libopencv-imgproc2.4
  libopencv-legacy-dev libopencv-legacy2.4 libopencv-ml-dev libopencv-ml2.4
  libopencv-objdetect-dev libopencv-objdetect2.4 libopencv-ocl-dev
  libopencv-ocl2.4 libopencv-photo-dev libopencv-photo2.4
  libopencv-stitching-dev libopencv-stitching2.4 libopencv-superres-dev
  libopencv-superres2.4 libopencv-ts-dev libopencv-ts2.4 libopencv-video-dev
  libopencv-video2.4 libopencv-videostab-dev libopencv-videostab2.4
  libopencv2.4-java libopencv2.4-jni libopenexr-dev libopenexr6 libopenjpeg2
  libopus0 libp11-kit-dev libpango1.0-dev libpathplan4 libphonon4
  libpixman-1-dev libpng12-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libpyside-dev
  libpyside-py3-1.2 libpyside1.2 libqt4-dev libqt4-dev-bin libqt4-opengl-dev
  libqt4-qt3support libqtwebkit-dev libraw1394-dev libraw1394-tools
  librtmp-dev libschroedinger-1.0-0 libshiboken-dev libshiboken-py3-1.2
  libshiboken1.2 libsm-dev libswscale-dev libswscale2
  libsys-hostname-long-perl libtasn1-6-dev libtbb2 libtiff5-dev libtiffxx5
  liburdfdom-dev liburdfdom-headers-dev liburdfdom-model-state0.2
  liburdfdom-model0.2 liburdfdom-sensor0.2 liburdfdom-world0.2 libva1
  libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk-media2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0 libx11-dev libx11-doc
  libx11-xcb-dev libx264-142 libxau-dev libxaw7-dev libxcb-dri2-0-dev
  libxcb-dri3-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-present-dev libxcb-randr0-dev
  libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-sync-dev
  libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxcb1-dev libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev
  libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxft-dev libxi-dev
  libxinerama-dev libxml2-utils libxmu-dev libxmu-headers libxpm-dev
  libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev libxshmfence-dev libxt-dev libxvidcore4
  libxxf86vm-dev libyaml-cpp-dev libyaml-cpp0.5 libzzip-0-13 libzzip-dev
  mesa-common-dev opencv-data phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer
  phonon-backend-gstreamer-common phonon-backend-gstreamer1.0 po-debconf
  python-opencv python-pycurl python-pyside python-pyside.phonon
  python-pyside.qtcore python-pyside.qtdeclarative python-pyside.qtgui
  python-pyside.qthelp python-pyside.qtnetwork python-pyside.qtopengl
  python-pyside.qtscript python-pyside.qtsql python-pyside.qtsvg
  python-pyside.qttest python-pyside.qtuitools python-pyside.qtwebkit
  python-pyside.qtxml python-qt4-dev python-sip-dev python-urlgrabber
  python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxversion qt4-linguist-tools qt4-qmake
  ros-indigo-angles ros-indigo-image-geometry ros-indigo-image-transport
  ros-indigo-interactive-markers ros-indigo-joint-state-publisher
  ros-indigo-kdl-conversions ros-indigo-kdl-parser ros-indigo-laser-geometry
  ros-indigo-map-msgs ros-indigo-media-export ros-indigo-orocos-kdl
  ros-indigo-pr2-description ros-indigo-python-orocos-kdl
  ros-indigo-python-qt-binding ros-indigo-resource-retriever
  ros-indigo-robot-state-publisher ros-indigo-rviz ros-indigo-tf
  ros-indigo-tf-conversions ros-indigo-tf2 ros-indigo-tf2-kdl
  ros-indigo-tf2-msgs ros-indigo-tf2-py ros-indigo-tf2-ros ros-indigo-urdf
  ros-indigo-urdf-parser-plugin ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial ros-indigo-xacro
  shiboken sip-dev x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-core-dev
  x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-dri2-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-gl-dev
  x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-render-dev
  x11proto-xext-dev x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev x11proto-xinerama-dev
  xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  curl fontconfig-config libcurl3 libfontconfig1 libgcrypt11 libharfbuzz-icu0
  libharfbuzz0b libidn11
8 to upgrade, 258 to newly install, 0 to remove and 44 not to upgrade.
Need to get 490 kB/98.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 399 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243428/sudo-apt-get-install-ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial-never-completes/) by [tge](https://answers.ros.org/users/27948/tge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-09-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-09**:
That's definitely not normal. Two things:

1. are you behind a proxy?
2. what is the initial output of `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial` (ie: which pkgs does it say it wants to install)?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-09**:
Also: [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/190828/apt-get-upgrade-stuck-at-the-same-package) is something that seems similar. The proxy thing comes up in the answers there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem turned out to be caused by the implicit proxy between my host machine and my VM. Changing the network interface from NAT to bridged solved the problem.
Thanks for the assistance.

---

Originally posted by [tge](https://answers.ros.org/users/27948/tge/) with karma: 16 on 2016-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-12**:
Good to hear you got it to work. Could you mark your question as answered by ticking the checkmark to the left of your answer? That way it's clear from the question listing that it's been resolved.

Thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-12**:
PS: for future questions: please *edit* your original post if you want/need to provide us with additional information or updates, instead of posting an answer. This is more of a Q/A site, than a regular forum. So answers are limited to a single one per user. Edits are used for discussion/updates.